# I am trying to open an img in a tkinter window, but the pillow library is giving my an error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to insert a photo in tkinter window python.
I am using the library PIL (pillow)
but it gives my an error

code:

```py
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(link))
my_label = Label(window, image=my_img)
my_label.place(x=x,y=y)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LitterHelper\main.py", line 86, in <module>
    i._img(window, 50, 150, "C:\\img\\Fries.gif")
  File "C:\Users\LitterHelper\main.py", line 5, in _img
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f))
                                ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

I want the image to open in the tkinter window

Comment: what does ‘p_img = Image.open(link)’ gives you?

Comment: The error is saying that the Image object doesn't have an open() method. It is likely because you are using an outdated version of the Pillow library. Make sure to update it to the latest version, and then try running the code again.

Comment: Thanks @CoolNetworking. But I am on the latest version, since I just installed yesterday via PyCharm and my pip is saying that am on PIl 9.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Something else in your code is overwriting `Image` with the `Image` class inside the `Image` module.  The result of doing:

```
from PIL import Image

print(type(Image))
```

should result in `module` being printed.  I get your error if after doing the above `import` I do:

```
Image.Image.open('foo.bar')
```

which prints your error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Somewhere else in your code you might be doing:

```
from PIL.Image import Image
```

or maybe you're assigning something to `Image`.

Comment: Thanks sam . but I don't want the image to open in the photo display app, I want the image to open in a tkinter window (GUI)